# Minimal polynomials Definition 3.4.1: A minimal polynomial of an element $α ∈ F_{q^m}$ with respect to $F_q$ is a nonzero monic p

Tags: ring-theory, coding-theory

## Minimal polynomials

Let $F_q$ be a subfield of $F_r$ . For an element $α$ of $F_r$ , we are interested in nonzero
polynomials $f (x) \in Fq [x]$ of the least degree such that $f (α) = 0$.

## Definition 3.4.1:

A minimal polynomial of an element $α ∈ F_{q^m}$ with respect to
$F_q$ is a nonzero monic polynomial $f (x)$ of the least degree in $F_q [x]$ such that
$f (α) = 0.$

Example $3.4.2$:
Let $α$ be a root of the polynomial $1 + x + x^2 ∈ F2[x]$. It is
clear that the two linear polynomials $x$ and $1+ x$ are not minimal polynomials
of $α$. Therefore, $1 + x + x^2$ is a minimal polynomial of $α$.
Since $1+(1+α)+(1+α)2 = 1+1+α +1+α2 = 1+α +α2 = 0$ and
$1 + α$ is not a root of $x$ or $1 + x, 1 + x + x^2$ is also a minimal polynomial of
$1 + α.$

Hi :)

I have an exposition in a few days on this tema, I have already seen this tema in ring theory, but now I can not use some properties ..

I could explain a little this, I know that $F_q$ is field of gallois but that means $F_{q^m}$

Comment: The theorems you need : the [multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54735/collecting-proofs-that-finite-multiplicative-subgroups-of-fields-are-cyclic). Therefore [there is (at most) one field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Existence_and_uniqueness) with $q$ elements. If $P\in\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $m$, then $\mathbb{F}_q[x]/(P)$ is a field with $q^m$ elements.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbf F_{q^m}$  is the *unique* (within a given algebraic closure of the prime subfield $\mathbf F_p$ of $\mathbf F_q$) extension field of degree $m$ of $\mathbf F_q$.

This field is isomorphic to $\mathbf F_q[X]/(f(X))$, where $f(X)$ is any irreducible polynomial in $\mathbf F_q[X]$.

Further, on can prove $\mathbf F_{q^m}\subset \mathbf F_{q^n}$ if and only if $m\mid n$.